# How to see MySQL update value for testing purpose?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an updated data mistake after updating data in MySQL database which has a select statement in the update process. I wonder if I can output the value which updated it using PHP to the browser to see the wrong value. I had googled it out and still had not found the answer.

Thanks :)

EDIT:

Example:

```
UPDATE table AS currData 
SET data1 = ((SELECT data1 
              FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS prevData 
              WHERE prevData.id < currData.id) + 1) 
LIMIT 1
```

I wish that I could output the select statement inside the update query which is the previous data.

Comment: Save your query as a variable -> `$sql = "UPDATE table SET col=1 WHERE id=10`. Then when you have an error, you can print the query as well -> `$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn)." The query was -> ".$sql);`

Comment: Sorry guys, I think I had mistakes while explaining my problem. I updated it with more clearly explanation.

Comment: Your example query could update any single row but the row with lowest id with data1 + 1 from any row but the row with the highest id. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Use a temporary table which is visible only to the current session. But your sample update is not clear, the sub-query is a little bit odd.